# Spanning header for gtsummary regression table

Tags: r, regression, gtsummary

I am using gtsummary package to tabulate my regression results.

With difficulty, I have tried to give my table a spanning header using the following function `modify_spanning_header(starts_with("stat_") ~ "**Logistic regression for years in US states**")`.

When I use this function along with the code below, I get the following response:

```
Error: Can't join on `x$column` x `y$column` because of incompatible types.
ℹ `x$column` is of type <character>>.
ℹ `y$column` is of type <integer>>.
```

Any idea what this could be? The full code which includes dummy data and packages is as follows:

```
 # load packages
library(gtsummary)


# dummy data 
crime <-data.frame(State = sample(c("SF", "AR", "NYC","MN"),13000,replace = TRUE),
                   Year = sample(as.factor(c(1990, 2000)),13000, replace = TRUE)
                   )

# logistic model with visual  
glm(Year ~ State, data = crime, family = binomial) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)
```

I am trying to follow and reproduce example two in this vignette - see [here](http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/modify.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue you're experiencing is that you're selecting all columns that begin with `"stat_"`. But in a `tbl_regression()` table, there are no columns that begin with `"stat_"`. Use the helper function `show_header_names()` to print the current column names along with their headers. This will help guide you to select the appropriate columns.  Example below.

```r
# load packages
library(gtsummary)


# dummy data 
crime <-data.frame(State = sample(c("SF", "AR", "NYC","MN"),13000,replace = TRUE),
                   Year = sample(as.factor(c(1990, 2000)),13000, replace = TRUE)
)

# logistic model with visual  
tbl <- 
  glm(Year ~ State, data = crime, family = binomial) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)

show_header_names(tbl)
#> 
#> 
#> Column Name   Column Header      
#> ------------  -------------------
#> label         **Characteristic** 
#> estimate      **OR**             
#> ci            **95% CI**         
#> p.value       **p-value**
#> i As a usage guide, the code below re-creates the current column headers.
#>   modify_header(update = list(
#>     label ~ "**Characteristic**",
#>     estimate ~ "**OR**",
#>     ci ~ "**95% CI**",
#>     p.value ~ "**p-value**"
#>   ))
# adding header here
tbl %>%
  modify_spanning_header(
    c(estimate, ci, p.value) ~ 
      "**Logistic regression for years in US states**")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Daniel,
I am trying to insert a header above the headers you listed. Kind of like the "Treatment received" header in example two of this vignette (http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/modify.html). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That is a table created with `tbl_summary()`, not with `tbl_regression()`. They are different tables with different column names.

`modify_spanning_header(c(estimate, ci, p.value) ~ "**Logistic regression for years in US states**")`